# Exponential Growth and Decay

Tags: calculus

Find the solution to
dy/dt=4y
satisfying
y(4)=9.
I am not sure where to begin. If I can get help with that I am sure I can finish the problem.

Comment: This is the reason they named it Grothendieck K-theory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory

Answer (score 1):

Separate variables:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y} \, dy &= 4 \, dt \\
\int \frac{1}{y} \, dy &= \int 4 \, dt \\
\ln y &= 4t + C
\end{align}
$$

Now use the fact that $y = 9$ when $t = 4$.
$$
\ln (9) = 4(4) + C
$$
So, $C = \ln 9 - 16$, which gives 
$$
y = e^{4t + (\ln 9 - 16)} = e^{\ln 9} e^{4t - 16} = 9e^{4t - 16}.
$$

Comment: No, could you explain further?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include more details.